# Trying to create a go back button on a form list

Tags: php, html, forms

So I'm new to PHP and I have this exercise I need to make that requires me to create using an  a button that can upload files to a certain folder in my computer then if it's successful it displays the contents of said folder. What I'm stuck with the fact that I'm having trouble implementing a "Go back" button when displaying that folder.

HTML code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadVer2.php" method="POST"> 
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="20000000" /> 
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" 
/><br /> 
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
$target_path = "LoadedFiles/"; 
$path="LoadedFiles/";

//echo "1. ". $target_path. "<br/>"; 
$target_path = $target_path . basename( 
$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);  

//echo "2. ". $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']."<br/>";
//echo "3. ". $target_path. "<br/>"; 


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], 
$target_path)) { 
    echo "The file ".  basename( 
$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).  
    " has been uploaded <br/>";
    
    $files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));
    /*
    $files[0] .
    $files[1] ..
    $files[2]
    */
    // print_r($files);
    $num=count($files);
    echo $num."<br/>";
    for($i=2; $i< $num+2; $i++){
        echo "<a href='http://localhost:80/public_html/LoadedFiles/$files[$i]'>$files[$i]</a><br/>";
    }
    
} else{ 
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try 
again!"; 
}
```

Don't know if it's possible, need some help kind strangers.

Comment: Can you further elaborate 'having trouble'. It seems like it could just be an `<a>` tag with a link that points to another page, but perhaps there's more to this...

Comment: Sorry english is not my main language so sorry if it's not pieced together well, but that little PHP script runs when I click the upload button in the HTML page to upload a random file then it displays a little list with the uploaded files in the folder (LoadedFiles). What I'm asking is if there is a way to implement a button to go back to the previous page. if I insert the button in the HTML it will not be displayed in said list.

Comment: I don't see the button in your code... can you add it? Even if it didn't work, it's easier to point out if you did something wrong than to just write the feature for you making all kinds of assumptions.

Comment: so i added something like this <a href="Index2.html">go back</a> in the HTML, but it does not appear in the said list.

Comment: Edit your question and add that link into your code. There's nothing wrong with that link, but there could be something wrong with where you place it.

Comment: ok so I'm just dumb i just simple needed to put <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">GO BACK</a>"; in the PHP file.